# Adding function to define a word

Tags: java, android

I have a word search game and I am planning to add a function to define the word selected.

it is something similar to these [Custom define word in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088001/custom-define-word-in-ios),
[How to use to Google Dictionary as an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740789/how-to-use-to-google-dictionary-as-an-api)

I have done the code as below

```
public void search(View view){
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    Log.d("TAG", "search: "+text);
    String url = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/"+text+"?s=t";
    //String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=define+"+text;
    Log.d("TAG", url);

    //webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.scrollTo(0,500);
}
```

Does someone have a better suggestion on how to implement this function?

1. offline
2. within the app itself

All help are much appreciated.

Remarks:
A word search game is 10 words per game, and let say a user play 5 game each day. that's 50 queries on api, 1000 user will be 50k queries, and 1.5 million per month for merely 1000 user.
Using API dictionary seems to be inappropriate in this case. What do you all think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an api from oxford dictionary for this purpose

Visit https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: This did actually add the function, but it will be costly and it is only functional when internet connected.
Any other alternative?

Comment: this page has a list of dictionary apis

Comment: thanks for the website, I will look through it and get back if i find something useful.